# Классический стиль программы в Delphi XE 10.2

Tags: delphi, vcl

Можно ли в Delphi XE 10.2 Tokyo сделать классический стиль VCL контролов на форме, как в Delphi 7 без XP-манифеста?

То есть нужен вариант как слева:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё оказалось до боли просто, нужно убрать галочку: Project -> Options... -> Application -> Enable Runtime Themes