# Delphi 10.2 - классический стиль во время проектирования?

Tags: delphi, интерфейс

После просмотра ответов на вопросы
[Классический стиль программы в Delphi XE 10.2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690129/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2-delphi-xe-10-2)  и 
[Не работает изменение цвета ProgressBar после перехода проекта с Delphi 6 на Delphi 10.2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764115/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-progressbar-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-delphi-6-%D0%BD%D0%B0-del) возник следующий вопрос:

1. можно ли сделать в Delphi 10.2, "классический стиль" (стиль Delphi 7), еще на ЭТАПЕ ПРОЕКТИРОВАНИЯ формы, а не на этапе выполнения "exe" (например, чтобы Label.Color изменяла цвет сразу после изменения его в *Object Inspector*).
2. Приведя максимально интерфейс Delphi 10.2 к стилю Delphi 7 ("пролазя" все настройки («Tools -> Options»)), я не смог избавиться от окна «Form Designer» (на котором располагается форма), т.е. окно «Form Designer» убрать, а форму, конечно, оставить. Если, конечно, можно.

P.S.
ну, на первый вопрос ответ нашел (точнее, подсказали): нужно свойство "*Transparent*", например, "*Label*", поставить в "*false*".
Интересно, это теперь что получается, что мне по всем старым проектам (от Delphi 7) нужно побегать и поустанавливать "Transparent" ("Label") = "false", чтоб конкретная окраска у всех компонентов при проектировании была?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, от `Form Designer` не избавиться: отныне это основной модуль проектирования форм в Delphi. Можно приблизить его к тому виду, какой он был в Delphi7: меню `Tools/Options`, вкладка `Form Designer`, убираем галку `Embedded Designer`, перегружаем IDE.

Comment: Галку "Embedded Designer" я еще убрал в самом начале... Да, жалко, придется привыкать. P.S: вот накой мне для проектирования делфийских приложений, здалась штука для кросс-платформенных приложений? только место забирает. (по крайней мере в help, я объяснения этому не нашел)